# Documentation of OCaml code in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ocaml

I'm using Eclipse with the OcaIDE-Plugin to write my ocaml-project.

I have written several ocaml-functions that I want to document (comment, return values and params).

I've created my documentation in the .ml-files like described in this link: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/ocamldoc.html

Here is an example of one function:

```
(** sorting tuples where first element is key *)
let my_comp x y = (*Some code*)
```

Unfortunately, my comments don't show up, when I press F2 at one of the functions, it only shows the name and the file it is contained.

When writing comments in an mli-file, it works as expected, but i also want to document "private" functions that are not accessible from the outside. Can I define functions in the mli, that are NOT accessible from the outside, just for the documentation?

How can I make Eclipse to show my documention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you said, you would like to show the documentation but not export the function out of the module. That, sadly, won't work.

I guess OcaIDE can be considered as incomplete but it doesn't look like it's something people care about (I don't know a single person working on OcaIDE). If you like having autocompletion etc, maybe try to program with emacs and install merlin (look, I found the perfect post for you : [here](https://opam.ocaml.org/blog/turn-your-editor-into-an-ocaml-ide/))

As for the suggestion of defining a function in the mli not accessible from the outside, it's completely opposed to why mli files are created, so don't expect that to be possible. ;-)

I hoped I've been able to help you.

Comment: I hope it is no a stupid question, but I don't get this line `Emacs. You will have to add opam/share to 'load-path and then load the plugin-specific file. This can be done by adding the following lines to your .emacs`. Where can I find the .emacs-file? I tried to locate it with `find / .emacs` and I manually searched in `~/.opam`, but couldn't find it...

Comment: It's not a stupid question. If you don't have any `.emacs` file just create one in your `home` directory and then add the lines that were written in it. In your home directory you should have a `.emacs.d` directory, don't put the `.emacs` in it, put it in the your `home` ;-)